# CopyFromRecordset vb.net equivalent for openxml spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, openxml

I have an app that I am adapting from a post I found here to build a nicely formatted spreadsheet using OpenXML. The tool connects to a db to get the data and builds 20 (ish) sheets. This part works fine. The problem I have is getting the data rows out. The method I originally tried was writing the sheet cell by cell, but each sheet could be upto 50k rows and so writing cell by cell is painfully slow.

The app I started from (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML) is a great introduction to the topic and has helped me enormously. There is even a method in the code already for AddTable. Unfortunately, it's not complete and no matter what I try I can't get the code right to make it work.

I have a datatable that I pass to the method, what I'm struggling to do is get the datatable to dump into the worksheet.

This is my code so far:

```
Public Shared Function AddTable(spreadsheet As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument, worksheet As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet, columnIndex As UInt32, rowIndex As UInt32, tbl As System.Data.DataTable)

    'Dim t As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Table
    Dim row As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row
    Dim sheetPart As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorksheetPart
    'Dim sheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet)
    Dim sheetData = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData()
    'Dim sheetPart = allWorksheetParts.Add(thisWorkbookpart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)(currentSheet.Id))
    'sheetPart.Worksheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData)

    sheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorksheetPart)()
    sheetPart.Worksheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData())
    sheetPart.Worksheet.Save()

    ' ' Add the sheet and make relation to workbook
    ' sheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet With {
    '.Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart),
    '.SheetId = (spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Count() + 1),
    '.Name = name}

    ' sheets.Append(sheet)
    ' spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()

    Dim strCols As String = ""
    'Dim arrColumns As List(Of String)

    Try
        For Each column In tbl.Columns
            row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row
            strCols = strCols & column.ColumnName & ","
            'arrColumns = strCols.Split(",")

            Dim cell As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
            cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName)
            row.AppendChild(cell)
        Next

        Dim arrColumns As New List(Of String)(strCols.Split(","c))
        worksheet.AppendChild(row).DefaultIfEmpty
        'sheetData.AppendChild(row).DefaultIfEmpty
        'worksheet.AppendChild(sheetData).DefaultIfEmpty
        'worksheet.AppendChild(row)

        For Each r In tbl.Rows
            Dim newRow As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
            For Each col In arrColumns
                Dim cell As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
                cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(r(col).ToString())
                newRow.AppendChild(cell)
            Next

            worksheet.AppendChild(newRow)
        Next

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Sorry it's so messy, I've tried all sorts of things to get it working.

The code doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't produce the populated sheets either.

Can anyone help me get the basics working?

Comment: There is no equivalent in the Open XML SDK for "dumping" data into a range or sheet. Cell-by-cell is really the only way. Performance is a known issue with the Open XML SDK. Things are somewhat faster if you create the raw XML then assign that to the .InnerXML of an element. But because of performance, people who have to work with large Excel files tend to use an alternative approach: SAX. See this article for example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx I recommend you do some research in that direction.